# Understanding a quote from G. H. Hardy in 'A Mathematician's Apology'

Tags: philosophy, constructive-mathematics

I recently learned about the philosophy of constructive mathematics. In [several](https://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/rabbithole.pdf) [discussions](https://unvarnishedveritas.wordpress.com/2003/10/16/reductio-ad-absurdum/) of the topic, I keep seeing a quote from G. H. Hardy's book *A Mathematician's Apology*;

> Reductio ad absurdum, which Euclid loved so much, is one of a
>   mathematician’s finest weapons. It is a far finer gambit than any
>   chess play: a chess player may offer the sacrifice of a pawn or a
>   piece, but a mathematician offers the game.

I understand what Reductio ad absurdum is, but I don't understand what this quote is saying. Can someone explain how a mathematician 'offers the game' by using this argumentative technique? Perhaps give a concrete example of this being used in a proof somewhere?

Thank you,

Comment: This is mostly poetic. You can imagine a proof as a game against an adversary who is trying to argue the opposite. A raa proof starts by assuming your adversary is correct (i.e. granting them victory) and arguing from those premises.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer do get this off the unanswered list.

Comment: Thank you :) accepted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mostly poetic. You can imagine a proof as a game against an adversary who is trying to argue the opposite. A reductio ad absurdum proof starts by assuming your adversary is correct (i.e. granting them victory) and arguing from those premises.